# Android Studio 3.0 layout rendering issue

Tags: android, android-layout, passwords, android-studio-3.0

I am integrating login screen layout with Android Studio 3.0, but on set input type password it create render issue.

Following is my sample XML file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/password"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/password"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_remember"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
            android:text="Remember Me"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/lable_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="forgotPassword"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
        android:onClick="attemptLogin"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Inside password Edit text if I am removing  `android:inputType="textPassword"`, it renders perfectly. Otherwise it create rendering issue.

Here are screenshot of error which I'm seeing on Layout editor:

[image]

Error in details

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
at java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:4454)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.getScriptFont(BidiRenderer.java:300)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.getScriptRuns(BidiRenderer.java:281)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.renderText(BidiRenderer.java:133)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.renderText(BidiRenderer.java:108)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.measureText(Paint_Delegate.java:1310)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nGetTextAdvances(Paint_Delegate.java:972)
at android.graphics.Paint.nGetTextAdvances(Paint.java)
at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:2287)
at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:181)
at android.text.TextUtils.setPara(TextUtils.java:1550)
at android.text.TextUtils.ellipsize(TextUtils.java:1257)
at android.text.TextUtils.ellipsize(TextUtils.java:1225)
at android.text.TextUtils.ellipsize(TextUtils.java:1203)
at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.calculateUsingTextSize(CollapsingTextHelper.java:610)
at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.calculateBaseOffsets(CollapsingTextHelper.java:430)
at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.recalculate(CollapsingTextHelper.java:651)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.onLayout_Original(TextInputLayout.java:1394)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.onLayout(TextInputLayout.java)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19623)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6095)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19623)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6095)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1552)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19623)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6095)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19623)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6095)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19623)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6095)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19623)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6095)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19623)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6095)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:346)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:546)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:680)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: 3.0 is in beta I think. So there may be some bug in the studio itself